# variation of f(x) prove the derive and continuous

Tags: real-analysis

consider the following function f

$$g(x) = { x^2 sin(1/x), x \ne 0 }$$
$$g(x) = 0, x= 0$$

can can you prove this is derivativable at point 0 using cauchy's definition?

and is this continuous on the point 0?

Comment: What is the limit of $g(x)$ as $x \to 0$?
What have you tried?

Comment: ok , since the g'(0) = 0 , derivative is exist. so its deferentiable. but I thought every differentiable point should be continuous. How to approach to prove this is not continuous?

Comment: This is the classic example of a function which has a discontinuous derivative. The only way I myself know to show g' is discontinuous at 0 is to actually take the derivative, and then show it has a discontinuity at 0. That all said, discontinuous derivatives exist mostly to teach you to be careful.  I don't know that they have any practical use.

Comment: Note that taking the limit at a point does not equate to taking the derivative at a point.
Also, it isn't necessary for $f'$ to be continuous for $f$ to be differentiable - but, of course, it is for $f''$ to exist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with "Cauchy's definition", so I'll assume it's the definition just about everyone uses.  Here is a hint.  $g'(0)$ exists if and only if the following limit exists (because it is the definition of $g'(0)$) and is finite:

$$g'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(h)}{h} = \ldots = \lim_{h\to 0} h\sin(\frac{1}{h}).$$

You can use the Squeeze Theorem with upper function $|h|$ and lower function $-|h|$ to find the value of the last limit (and prove it exists).

Once you have proven $g'(0)$ is well-defined and found its value, there is no need to prove separately that $g$ is continuous at $x=0$ ($g$ must be continuous at $x=0$ in order for $g'(0)$ to exist).

Comment: if f(x) is derivatable , then f(x) is guranted to be continuous?

Comment: @Kingkong : Yes.  I'll use $a$ instead of $x$, because I find it less confusing.  $f'(a) = \lim_{h\to 0}(f(a+h)-f(a))/h$.  If $f'(a)$ exists (and is a finite number), then the limit exists and is finite, and since the denominator goes to zero as $h \to 0$, the numerator $f(a+h)-f(a)$ goes to zero as $h\to 0$, so $\lim_{h\to 0} (f(a+h)-f(a))=0$, which is equivalent to $\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h)=f(a)$, which is equivalent to $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$, which is the definition of $f$ being continuous at $x=a$.

Comment: how about continuous -> derivatable ?

Comment: @Kingkong: no.  The classic example is $f(x)=|x|$, which is continuous at $x=0$, but not differentiable at $x=0$.